# probleme dealing with several view in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, contentcontrol

i'am currently building a software who as several view and i would like to switch from one view to another by clicking on a button on the current view :
[image]

of course i have more than 3 views but it's to illustrate the concept. here is my code to go from page 1 to page 2. but i have trouble to go from page 2 to page 3 i don't know what's wrong. thank you for your help.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="maquette.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"     
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:maquette"
        xmlns:viewModel ="clr-namespace:maquette.ViewModel"
        xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:maquette.View"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:page1ViewModel}">
            <local:Page1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:page2ViewModel}">
            <view:Page2/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:page3ViewModel}">
            <view:Page3/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:page4ViewModel}">
            <view:Page4/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Controls:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="pagesControl"  
                                              Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"
                                              Transition="Left"
                                              />
    </Grid>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new NavigationViewModel();

    viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new page1ViewModel(viewModel);

    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

NavigationViewModel.cs

```
public class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private object selectedViewModel;

    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="maquette.Page1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:maquette.View"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:maquette.ViewModel"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d"       
             >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Width="320"  
                   FontSize="30"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                   FontWeight="Bold">File Control Program</TextBlock>


        <Button x:Name="button" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Width="180" 
                Height="90"
                Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding Path=goSettings}"
                >
            <TextBlock Text="go page 2"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

page1ViewModel

```
class page1ViewModel
{
    public ICommand goSettings { get; set; }

    private readonly NavigationViewModel _navigationViewModel;

    public page1ViewModel(NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel)
    {
        _navigationViewModel = navigationViewModel;
        goSettings = new BaseCommand(OpenSettings);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    private void OpenSettings(object obj)
    {
        _navigationViewModel.SelectedViewModel = new page2ViewModel();
    }
}
```

page2.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="maquette.View.Page2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:maquette.View"
             xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:maquette.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Background="White">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Width="180" 
                Height="80"
                Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding Path=goPage3}">
            <TextBlock Text="Go page 3"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20"
                       />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

page2.cs

```
public Page2()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     var viewModel = new NavigationViewModel();
     DataContext = new page2ViewModel(viewModel);
}
```

page2ViewModel.cs

```
    public class page2ViewModel
    {

        public ICommand goPage3 { get; set; }

        private readonly NavigationViewModel _navigationViewModel;

        public page2ViewModel()
        {

        }
        public page2ViewModel(NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel)
        {
            _navigationViewModel = navigationViewModel;
            goPage3 = new BaseCommand(OpenPage3);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        private void OpenPage3(object obj)
        {
            _navigationViewModel.SelectedViewModel = new page3ViewModel();
        }
}
```

But as i said the transition between the page 2 and 3 doesn't work. any help ? thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this constructor overload from `page2ViewModel`:

```
public page2ViewModel()
{

}
```

And always inject it with the one and only `NavigationViewModel` in page1ViewModel:

```
private void OpenSettings(object obj)
{
    _navigationViewModel.SelectedViewModel = new page2ViewModel(_navigationViewModel);
}
```

Also don't set the `DataContext` of `Page2` explicitly:

```
public Page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The data templating will make sure that it gets the correct `DataContext`.

Comment: ok, but then from page 2 to page 3 should i put :                            private void OpenPage3(object obj)
        {
            _navigationViewModel.SelectedViewModel = new    page3ViewModel(_navigationViewModel);
        }

Comment: and in page3ViewModel :         private readonly NavigationViewModel _navigationViewModel;
        public page3ViewModel(NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel)
        {
            _navigationViewModel = navigationViewModel;
        }  ??

Comment: Yes, all view models that should be able to navigate should be injected with a reference to the NavigationViewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

**This is for Without using any mvvm framework**

Define Data Templates for child viewmodels in Main window viewmodel.

For entire application u have to create static object for your main view model.

Then only views will be changed.

It should be like this...

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;

    public App()
    {
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

In MainWindow Viewmodel

```
 public class MainWindowViewmodel
    {

        private object selectedViewModel;

        public object SelectedViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");
            }
        }
        public MainWindowViewmodel()
        {
            SelectedViewModel = new page1viewmodel();
        }
    }
```

In Page1Viewmodel in

```
class page1ViewModel
{
public ICommand goSettings { get; set; }

private readonly NavigationViewModel _navigationViewModel;

public page1ViewModel(NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel)
{
    _navigationViewModel = navigationViewModel;
    goSettings = new BaseCommand(OpenSettings);
}
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj"></param>
private void OpenSettings(object obj)
{
   mainWindowViewModel.SelectedViewModel   = new page2ViewModel();
}
```

}

like this you have to implement.

This will help you.